# scandir iterator not behaving according to documentation (Win10, py 3.9.6)

Tags: python, windows, file, directory, operating-system

*EDIT: Colons are if statements are really kind of important, aren't they?*

I'm having terrible difficulty getting a list of files in my working data directory.  Have tried listdir and scandir to same result, a Syntax Error raise at runtime start, before it even transitions over to the IDLE window.

```
import os
import numpy
import pandas as pd

i = 0
for f in os.scandir(r'C:\\Users\\scott.d.lee\\Desktop\\datafiles'):
  i = i + 1
  print("processing file #",i,"[",f,"] ...")
  this_df = pd.read_csv(f, skipinitialspace=True, header=0, index_col="sid", on_bad_lines='warn', names=cols)
  print(this_df.columns)
```

And it's blowing up on the for-loop line, believing there's a syntax error at the end of that line.
Any ideas, o friendly spirits of the internet?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  you need double \\ for each \ in your scan dir path.  i.e. ```c:\\Users\\scott.d.lee\\Desktop\\datafiles```.  Aside for that, please clarify what you mean by 'blowing up'.

Comment: `print("processing file #",i,,"[",f,"] ...")` seems to have an extra comma: `i,,` should be `i,`. Keep in mind when you get `SyntaxError`s, you should also check the line(s) preceding the location of the line shown the error message.

Comment: thanks for the pointers - both valid, but neither seem to be the root of the problem.  "blows up" means i'm getting a red line highlight on the for...in line, which shows up as a popup box SyntaxError described "invalid syntax" when i attempt to run.  i have tried it with and without the raw string modifier, both listdir and scandir.  regular file opening using pandas a la Panda's read_csv if i set the name of the file explicitly works just fine.

Comment: oh guys i feel like a maroon.  MISSING COLON.  hair on fire.